# Drawing a polygon in a Google Maps Angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I've been reading about the updates of dependencies but couldn't find which are the correctly most recent. Also I've read the documentation of GM and Ng and still don't know which options should I use.

So far I was able to render the map with an initialized 4 coordinates polygon.

```
export class MapComponent {
  title = 'Google Maps';
  polygonPoints: google.maps.LatLngLiteral[] = [
    { lat: -34.5, lng: -58.4 },
    { lat: -34.5, lng: -59.4 },
   { lat: -35.5, lng: -59.4 },
   { lat: -35.5, lng: -58.4 },
 ];
 options = {
   mapTypeId: "satellite",
   streetViewControl: false,
   fullscreenControl: false
 }
 bsAs = {
  lat: -34.6118,
  lng: -58.4173,
 }
 vic = {
   lat: -32.62014554060702,
   lng: -60.149028935272156
 }
 position = this.bsAs
 zoom = 8
 centerVic() {
  this.position = this.vic
   this.zoom = 10
 }
}
```

I'm thinking about adding a function with a listener of the coordinates of the clicks on the map to set them in this object since this is rendered fine:

```
 polygonPoints: google.maps.LatLngLiteral[] = [
   { lat: -34.5, lng: -58.4 },
    { lat: -34.5, lng: -59.4 },
    { lat: -35.5, lng: -59.4 },
   { lat: -35.5, lng: -58.4 },
  ];
```

But I'm wondering if is this the right way to do it or there is something way faster..